# how to reload data after used $emit in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

i have some question about angularJs.. how to re init some variable in scope after i used emit . example code:

```js
$scope.uiConfig = {title: "example"};

$scope.$emit('myCostumCalendar', 'Data to send');

$scope.$on('myCostumCalendar', function () {
  $scope.uiConfig = {title: "new Title"};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback you pass to $on received parameters with your data:

```
$scope.$on('myCostumCalendar', function (event, data) {
  // data will store your sent data
  $scope.uiConfig = {title: "new Title"};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  myApp.controller('mainEventController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
  }]);
  myApp.controller('EventController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    debugger;  

    $scope.$on('MyEvent', function() {
       debugger;
 
      $scope.count++;
    });
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Basic on controllers</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="basiccontroller.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
 
  <!-- emit and broadcast -->
  <p><b>emit and broadcast</b></p>
  <p>----------------------------</p>
   <div ng-controller="mainEventController">
  Root scope <tt>MyEvent</tt> count: {{count}}
  <ul>
   <li ng-controller="EventController">
    <button ng-click="$emit('MyEvent')">$emit('MyEvent')</button>
    <button ng-click="$broadcast('MyEvent')">$broadcast('MyEvent')</button>
    <br>
    Middle scope <tt>MyEvent</tt> count: {{count}}
    <ul>
     <li  ng-controller="EventController">
      Leaf scope <tt>MyEvent</tt> count: {{count}}
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul> 
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is not giving proper result :

inherited scope value will not give proper result in $ emit function and first time emit function will not work in angular js as expected.

Plz any clarify it .

Comment: if you have some problem with your code, just ask a new question, not by answer like this way.